# I want to make a Discord.js reaction collector, counter, timer and role dm

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I made a suggestion command which sends an embed with the suggestor name and the suggestion to a specific channel. It then reacts with  and .

How can I make a collector, that counts the reactions and after e.g 1 week it stops it and DMs everyone in a specific role (e.g *Staff*) with the results and edits the embed in the channel saying *Suggestion accepted/denied*.

Also, how can I make a collector that runs a command with permissions (roles e.g
**Staff**)

I know I am asking for a lot, but I looked at discord.js.org's documentation and I couldn't understand it.
Thanks for taking off your time to help me!

Here is my code so far:

```js
if (command === 'suggest') {
 if (!args.length) {
  const suggestHelp = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle('Suggestions')
   .setDescription('Help')
   .addField('Usage', 'The easiest way for community to rate suggestions!')
   .addField(
    'Commands',
    '`/suggest` Displays info about the suggestions \n `/suggest <suggestion>` Make a suggestion, which can be rated by the community'
   )
   .setFooter('Powered by Monebot')
   .setColor(0x2e86c1);
  message.channel.send(suggestHelp);
  return;
 } else if (args.length) {
  let suggestor = message.author.username;
  let suggestionText = args.slice(0).join(' ');
  const suggestEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setDescription(suggestionText)
   .setColor(0xf5b041)
   .setAuthor(`Suggestion from ${suggestor}`);
  //.setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
  client.channels.cache
   .get('ID')
   .send(suggestEmbed)
   .then((messageReaction) => {
    //Setup 1 Channel ID for suggestions
    messageReaction.react('');
    messageReaction.react('');
   });
 }
}
```

Comment: What are you having issues on? I would suggest you try to make everything you listed before coming to here, do you have an error?

Answer (score 0):

You are not specific with what you want us to help you with.
You're asking us too much to do in one time and you litterally gave us you code and asked us to change it ^^'

But i get what you are trying to do so i suggest you to search in a [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html) wich is extremelt helpful in this case

If i helped you can approuve this suggestion, if not please edit yours so that we can help you.

- Markdown would be helful

And i have the same question as ortogonal

> What are you having issues on? I would suggest you try to make everything you listed before coming to here, do you have an error?